# Custom journey activity always goes only in one direction

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Custom journey activity of type Decision Split always goes in the first branch. Even when I hardcode the outcome in execute endpoint as such (in C#)

```
return Json(new { branchResult = "Remaining" });
```

My config contains outcomes array:

```
"outcomes": [
    {
      "arguments": {
        "branchResult": "firstBranchKey"
      },
      "metaData": {
        "label": "Decision 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "arguments": {
        "branchResult": "remainingBranchKey"
      },
      "metaData": {
        "label": "Remaining"
      }
    }
  ]
```

What might be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Is that possible that you have duplicated contacts entering the journey?

Comment: No, it's not. I tried on DE that contains only 3 contacts, and they were created manually.